# Techniques to refresh an access token using OAuth 2 on iOS platform

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0

I'm writing an app that uses OAuth 2 (third-party app that uses Google Account) fot make the auth. The auth is composed of 2 steps.

1. GET request to obtain the code
2. POST request to exchange the code obtained in the 1st step with an access_token and a refresh token.

When the access_token (about 5 min) expires is possible to **exchange the refresh_token with a new access_token**.

My question is must check if my access token is expired or for example every 4 min I must refresh my access_token for example using NSTimer?

Wich are the typical solution to solve my problem? 
Thanks

Comment: did you manage to figure this out? How do you get the refresh token? Thanks for you're help :)

Comment: You sjould get the refresh token together with an access token, and then when you get response wit the current access token 'unauthorized', you automatically try to refresh token and continue on success or go to login on failure

Comment: I think that you can store the time when you got the access_token and check it before you are going to send post request. But you also need to check the request result in case the access_token is invalid in some reason.